# How to replace if starts and ends with a particular letter using single Regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I can do with two `replace` but how can do with using single `replace`

```js
console.log("NoZtestZ".replace(/^Z/, '').replace(/Z$/, ""))
console.log("ZtestZ".replace(/^Z/, '').replace(/Z$/, ""))
```

Comment: Personally, I'd use an untypeable character, so that I don't get false positives. "Zebras are awesome" becomes something else. Hopefully you are only using "Z" as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an alternative and replace global.

```js
console.log("ZteZstZ".replace(/^Z|Z$/g, ''));
```